# Why BassBoost in Android lowers audio level?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, audioeffect

I use BassBoost effect on my audio application. But when I enable it, audio goes down automatically even though the visible volume level is still at the top.

```
bassBoost.setStrength((short) 1000);
bassBoost.setEnabled(true);
```

What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's quite likely that the `BassBoost` effect attenuates the input signal to leave some headroom for the effect, in order to avoid clipping.